# Change opacity of an image inside a div while also changing the color of the text below it without changing the opacity

Tags: css

This is probably so easy and I'm just not getting it. I'm trying to make it where when you hover over the whole div it changes the images opacity while changing the color of the font below it (but not changing the opacity of the font).

See example of what I mean here---> http://www.golfcarsofdallas.com/cart-finder/new-carts/club-car/commercial/

Here's the code I have, but it will only change the color if I hover over the text and the opacity if I hover over the image. Not the div as a whole.

```
.showroom-models-big img {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    }

.showroom-models-big p {
    margin-top: -40px;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-align: center;
    }

.showroom-models-big a {
    color: #000000;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
   }

.showroom-models-big img:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
   }
.showroom-models-big a:hover {
    color: #35c411;
   }
```

Comment: Can you also post the html, so I can replicate this?

Answer (score 2):

you have to set the `:hover` to the div followed by the elements inside of it like this example.

```css
.container {
  background: #fff;
  display:inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
.container:hover img {
  opacity: .6;
}
.container:hover p {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://www.golfcarsofdallas.com/wp-content/uploads/streetlegal.jpg" alt="">
  <p>Some text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You're the best!! I spent 2 1/2 hours trying to figure out why it wasn't working. Too stubborn to ask the question. Thank you so much!!